# VBA Replace in Word from Excel including headers, footers and footnotes

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, header

I have some data on an Excel file which I want to search-replace into a Word document through an Excel VBA macro. There are two columns: one with the things I want to look for, and another one for the replacement text. That works fine.

The problem is that I want to replace also inside the HEADERS, FOOTERS, FOOTNOTES and ENDNOTES. I've tried some code with things from the Internet, but it does not fulfill its mission... Any help?

```
Sub ReplacetoWord()

Dim rngStory As Word.Range
Dim lngJunk As Long
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim name_book As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Filename As String
Dim wArch As String

name_book = ThisWorkbook.FullName
x = Split(name_book, Application.PathSeparator)
Filename = x(UBound(x))

Sheets("Generate_Report").Select
wArch = Range("C3").Text & Range("C2").Text & ".docx"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Documents.Open wArch
objWord.Visible = True

Workbooks(Filename).Activate
Worksheets("Generate_Report").Select

'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType

For i = 1 To Range("I1").Value 'cell with the number of data to replace

Workbooks(Filename).Activate
Worksheets("Generate_Report").Select

datos = Range("B" & i).Text 'what to look for
reemp = Range("A" & i).Text 'what to replace with

  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      With objWord.Selection.Find
       .Text = datos 
       .Replacement.Text = reemp 
       .Wrap = wdFindContinue
       .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
      End With
      On Error Resume Next
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
      Case 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
        If rngStory.ShapeRange.count > 0 Then
          For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
              With objWord.Selection.Find
                .Text = datos 
                .Replacement.Text = reemp 
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
              End With
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
      End Select
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next


Next i

objWord.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Footnotes collection.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Footnote footnote in word.ActiveDocument.Footnotes)
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = footnote.Range;
     range.Find.Text = "find me";
     range.Find.MatchWholeWord = true;
     range.Find.Execute(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

     if (range.Find.Found == true)
     {
         // Whatever you need to do.
     }
 }
```